# Can my leafless rosemary plant recover?

Tags: transplanting, rosemary

I have this rosemary plant in my raised garden bed that unfortunately went through both my neglect and some tough heat waves last year.

This year I was planning to plant a new one, but when I went to remove this one the roots seemed really healthy, and all the stems you see here are flexible and green inside.

It's been about 3 weeks since I've replanted it and have been watering every day. Can this rosemary recover? It's clearly still alive, but I don't know if it can grow without any new leaves.

[image: rosemary bush]

Answer (score 1):

Unlikely, but it might, depends how much patience you have to wait and see. Rosemary does not leaf out on older wood, but you might be lucky and get some leaves appear on the top, newer growth. If leaves don't appear within a month or so, remove it and replace.

Comment: Just to add: stop watering. "Watering every days" is too much for most plants, in particular to rosemary and other Mediterranean plants which like dry soil.